# syntax error near unexpected token on a simple zimbra fillter setting script

Tags: linux, bash, zimbra

ok, So i'm running zimbra 7 on centos 6, and, using different sources, i wrote the following script:

```
MAIL="$(< scripts\mails.txt)" #mails from mails.txt file
for MAIL in $MAILS; do
zmmailbox -z -m $MAILS cf -c red "/SPAM"
zmmailbox -z -m $MAILS afrl "Spam" active any header "subject" contains "your account" header "subject" contains "facebook" header "subject" contains "google" header "subject" contains "paypal" header "subject" contains "virus" header "subject" contains "invoice" fileinto "SPAM" stop   
done
```

but whenever i run it (as a zimbra user) i get the following error:

```
./fillter-set.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `zmmailbox'
./fillter-set.sh: line 5: `zmmailbox -z -m $MAILS cf -c red "/SPAM"'
```

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong and how can i fix the script so i could run it?

Comment: Looks to me like the the `zimbra user` has no privilege to access the `zmmailbox` script/binary.  How about running the command script with `sudo`?

Comment: same thing happens, but `zmmailbox` is a zimbra's command. I cant run it (or any zimbra command for that matter) if i dont do `su - zimbra`

Comment: Check the file permissions of `zmmailbox` and post it here..Also, is there a group called `zimbra` in `/etc/group`.

Comment: If `zimbra` group exists then try running `useradd -G zimbra your_user_name`  as root. I am guessing the members of the of the `zimbra` group` should by default have the permission to execute `zimbra` commands

Comment: im not sure how to see permissions for `zmmailbox` since it's just a command not a file. there is zimbra group in `/etc/group`. and im doing all commands from root user and/or as zimbra user, for specific zimbra commands.